# Select multiple slices in pandas dataframe using a list or another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, vectorization, slice, apply

I have a massive dataframe with column ["data"] that I need to create multiple smaller sets of dataframes with. I want to select df["data"][1:3], df["data"][4:5] at once without having to use a for loop and iterate selecting each slice.

Either a vectorized solution or .apply solution would make this much faster

Something like using below dataframe (called "selection") as the indexing input:

| from | to. |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 5. |

and trying to do something like: df["data"][selection["from"]:selection["to"]]
and it would output df[1:3], df[4:5].

Comment: Just to clarify: are you trying to select rows or columns? `df[1:3]` selects columns 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: rows - trying to select rows 1:3 and rows 4:5 all at once without having to for loop